# SQL SELECT query not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have an sql query:

`SELECT * FROM presentations_db.presenters_tbl WHERE e-mail LIKE '%@%';`

It does not seem to work and I don't know why. If I remove the WHERE part it works, but includes all records. I only want records that have an e-mail address. I am using mysql workbench. The e-mail field is a VARCHAR(45). It seems so simple but not... There is no feedback or error messages. The result list doesn't even open.

Comment: I have checked the following:

Comment: e-mail field exists and is spelt correctly. presentations_db.presenters_tbl exists and is spelt correctly.

Comment: The fact that it works without the WHERE part tells me there must be a problem with the e-mail field, but what??

Comment: see my explanation below, it perform arithmetic operation.

Comment: If possible, I'd recommend changing your column name to e_mail - DB objects whose name contain special characters are always terrible to work with (this also applies to umlauts / accents / case-sensitive names).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must wrap the column name with backtick to avoid syntax error.

```
SELECT * FROM presentations_db.presenters_tbl WHERE `e-mail` LIKE '%@%
```

if you don't wrap it with backtick, it will perform artihmetic operation:

> **mail** is subtracted from **e**

causing you to receive this error message: `Unknown column 'e' in 'where clause'`

---

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00589/3)

Answer (score 0):

you query is right just replace this

```
    e-mail
```

by this

```
   `e-mail`
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the required quoting with back-ticks or double quotes (if ANSI quoting is enabled) I'd change the where clause this:

```
SELECT * FROM presentations_db.presenters_tbl WHERE `e-mail` IS NOT NULL;
```

since all you want is the records which have an e-mail set. It doesn't check for validity of the address, however.